# Why "a in b == c" is equal to "(a in b) and (b == c)"

Tags: python

I found that the result of evaluating `a in b == c` is always equal to `(a in b) and (b == c)`. Could anyone explain that?

Here is an example running on Python3.7:

```
>>>> "123" in "1234" == "1234"
True

>>>> "123" in "1234" != "1234"
False

>>>> "123" in "1234" != "12345"
True

>>>> "123" in "1234" == "12345"
False

>>>> "888" in "1234" == "1234"
False
```

Comment: It works exactly the same as `1 < 2 < 3`.

Comment: @Selcuk the putative dupe is a laughably horrendously bad fit for this question.

Comment: @hobbs I disagree. The question confirms the findings of this one, and the answer explains how it works internally. I am happy to add another duplicate to the list of duplicates if you suggest one though.

Comment: Nice question. I hadn't appreciated how weird chaining can get!

Comment: The 1st dupe was not perfect, I added another one, which isn't perfect either. But there is no clear canonical dupe. I would even consider reopening this in case someone can answer it well, that would help the community I think and we can refer back to it.

Comment: @jamylak I had been writing it :)

Comment: @hobbs I'll just reopen it, don't see any harm in that

Comment: Why are those expressions equivalent? Because the Python language designers decided they would be. There's not much more to it than that.

Comment: The `and` isn't explicitly added, the `in`, `==` and `!=` are evaluated left to right https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: The relevant section of the docs is this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: @jamylak: I added new dupes, pretty sure the first two are basically perfect (even combining the same two operators).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Feel free to close it again if you see fit, I see your point, I just thought that there wasn't 1 big detailed answer that got enough attention, but yes the first two do answer it

Answer (score 1):

[Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is **equivalent to x < y and y <= z**, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false

Where `in` is also a comparison operator

Also refer section on [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) to see that `in` and equality checks occur at the same time, left to right